# laravel auth Error .Can't get user information

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i think everything is right userLogin.php
on page **auth :: guard ('students') -> check ();**
command returns me the user, but on the page after logging in, it always shows the user null
userLogin.php (controller)

```
 if(auth::guard('students')->attempt(['email'=>$request->student_mail,'password'=>$request->student_password],false))
            {
                //dd(Auth::guard('students')->check());
               
               return redirect()->route('student.home');
               
            }
            else 
            {
               echo "yannlış";
               
            }
```

web.php (routes)

```
Route::post('login', [userLogin::class, 'loginPost'])->name('login.post');

Route::get('student/home', [studentHome::class, 'index'] )->name('student.home')->middleware('auth:students');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');


});
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2t5k.jpg).

Comment: so you and Emre ŞİMŞEK are working on the same exact project?

Comment: yes we still couldn't solve

Comment: can you show the `studentHome` controller

Comment: `StudentHome ` file is empty @lagbox

Comment: 'm using a middleware  @lagbox
` 
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
       
        if(!auth::guard('students')->check())
        {
            return redirect()->route('testDeneme');
        }
        
        return $next($request);
    }
`

Comment: its possible you have a session/cookie issue going on here ... though i don't know where you have this middleware assigned

Comment: I can only get user information on userLogin page. Like you said
There is a session problem. We tried many methods and still haven't solved them. 
  @lagbox

Comment: how are you serving this site?

Comment: student internship application automation @lagbox

Comment: how are you serving this site? apache, nginx, artisan serve? on a web host?

Comment: use artisan serve

Comment: try `request('students')->user()` OR `auth('students')->user()`